# Batching agents based on arrivalnode

Tags: anylogic, batching

In my Anylogic model, my source block generates agents on different nodes based on a database values defining which node the agent has to arrive.

The orders at the same location arrive at the same time (so for example at 7:30, 3 agent orders arrive at node1 and 4 agent order arrive at node2).

Now what I want to do is that the orders at node1 make a batch of 1x2 and 1x1 and I want that the orders at node2 to form a batch 2. These agents than will seize a transporter which transports these batches to the same location and than unbatch.

So my question is how will I create batches based on the arrivallocation loaded from the database.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a variable in the agents `myNode` of type `RectangularNode`. Store the node the agents are being positioned at in the Source block.

Use a `SelectOutput` block downstream of the `Source´ block that splits the agents by their current node.

Then, use batch objects as usual as the arriving agents are now split by their node location.

Comment: Hi @Benjamin, Thanks for the answer. But if I've let say 100 locations, do I then have to create a select output with 100 different outputs and manually splitting them or is there a more efficient and simple solution.

Comment: Always add those details to the question upfront ;) Best open a new issue with that specific question, easier to reply

Comment: Sorry, I will do!